# AWS autoscaling ELB forward requests to instance not yet ready to take requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have setup auto-scaling on AWS. I noticed, whenever I add a new instance to my auto scaling group my load balancer starts sending traffic to new instance even if its not yet ready to handle traffic and result is 502 Bad Gateway.

I have set **Health Check Grace Period** to **300** but I feel ELB doesn't wait for this time and starts forwarding traffic to newly added instance.

Can you please guide me how I can ensure ELB waits for my instance to be ready to handle requests.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your health check URL may be returning 200 too early.

Comment: @titogeo- please see attached image above - what do you suggest?

Comment: is 300 enough for your application to be fully up? Is your health check waiting for your application to load?

Comment: Are you doing some processing on startup? If so you must wait for all those processes to finish before letting your heartbeat.php return a 200.

Comment: @Bob - no, new instance is booting from an AMI which contains per-configured LAMP setup with PHP and Laravel code mounted from EFS.

Comment: @titogeo - no health check is not waiting for grace period as well. I have tried with grace period of 8mins but still I am getting these 502s on 5mins. Means my grace period settings not working.